# PostgreSQL COPY IN and NPGSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, bulkinsert, npgsql

I'm trying to copy data from stream to postgres. 
I've prepared file fl.ext:

1<kbd>Tab</kbd>one<kbd>Return</kbd>
2<kbd>Tab</kbd>two<kbd>Return</kbd>
3<kbd>Tab</kbd>three<kbd>Return</kbd>
4<kbd>Tab</kbd>slony<kbd>Return</kbd>

And wrote test code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Console.ReadLine());
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format("COPY {0}(id, text) FROM STDIN;", tableName), connection);
NpgsqlCopyIn cin = new NpgsqlCopyIn(cmd, connection, sr.BaseStream);
connection.Open();
cin.Start();
cin.End();
cin.Close();
```

But it fails on `cin.Start()` with `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}` and no additional details. 
What I'm doind wrong, guys?

Answer (score 1):

Solved just by moving `NpgsqlCommand` and `NpgsqlCopyIn` declarations after `connection.Open();`. Now works fine.